# Amount doubles when trying to LEFT JOIN tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables

**Customers Table**

[image]

```
CustomerID, LastName,
```

**Transactions Table**

[image]

```
TransID, CustomerID, Price,
```

**Payments Table**

[image]

```
PaymentID, CustomerID, Paid,
```

I'm trying to make a query to get total balance by combining the `CustomerID` & `Price` & `Paid` then do `Price - Paid` and get a total balance.

I tried:

```
SELECT [Customers].LastName, SUM(Transactions.Price) AS [Total Price], SUM(Payments.Paid) AS [Total Paid], SUM(Transactions.Price - Payments.Paid) AS Balance
    FROM ([Customers] LEFT JOIN Payments ON Payments.CustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID) LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.CustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
    GROUP BY [Customers].LastName;
```

But the Total `Paid` amount doubles from the real payment amount (*For Example:* If Customer has a $150 balance & makes payment of $65 it will show me Total Paid = $130 and in results it will make the Total Balance as $20 instead of $85).

**Query Results**

[image]

As a side note the Total `Balance` Column only gives me the Balance if there was a payment made already. If there was no payment made yet for a specific CustomerID it is blank instead of the current balance amount.

Please Help!!!

Comment: This looks like an issue with duplication. Are there duplicate customer ID's in your [Customers] table?

Comment: No there is only 1

Comment: Can you show a small example of your table contents?

Comment: Somewhere you are likely to have more than one id.

Comment: Try with UNION and then SUM. I have given one example in answer. I have tested and it worked.

Comment: THe issue is likely one of cardinality  a customer can have.  zero or may transactions and a customer can have zero or many payments.  but the relationship between payments to transactions is N:N  the simplest way to solve this is to use subqueries to total before the joins.  Thereby ensuring a 1:1:1 cardinality between table joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below query:

```
SELECT [A].LastName, (SUM(A.PaidAmt) - SUM(PriceAmt) ) AS Amt

FROM (
SELECT
    [Customers].LastName, (Payments.Paid) as PaidAmt , 0 AS PriceAmt

FROM [Customers]
LEFT JOIN Payments
    ON Payments.CustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID


UNION

SELECT
    [Customers].LastName, 0 as PaidAmt , (Transactions.Price) AS PriceAmt
FROM [Customers]
LEFT JOIN Transactions
    ON Transactions.CustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
) A
GROUP BY A.LastName;
```

This should work.

Comment: Works!!! But shows Debit as Credit (Debit is surrounded with ($20.00) ) Credit as Debit without $20.00 - can you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: like this  ( SUM(PriceAmt) - SUM(A.PaidAmt) )

Comment: It should show the value even if there is no payment. Since LEFT OUTER join has been used it must work in all cases and you should see value.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you getting double, triple or more amount? The issue is one of cardinality. If payments and transactions are both a 1:M relationship with customer; and have no relationship between them other than customer, then the records are being duplicated when you don't want them to be.  Assume we have the following # of records all related to customer 1

1. Customer: 1
2. Payments: 2
3. Transactions: 2

What you think is happening when a join occurs is:

```
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------+------+--+-------+
| CustomerID | LastName | TransactionID | Price | PaymentID | Paid |  | Total |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------+------+--+-------+
| 1          | Smith    | 1             | 150   | 1         | 20   |  |       |
| 1          | Smith    | 3             | 30    | 3         | 40   |  |       |
|            |          |               | 180   |           | 60   |  |   120 |
```

When what is actually happening is: (the engine doesn't know how to tie payment to transaction so it has to tie each transaction to all payments!)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CustomerID | LastName | TransactionID | Price | PaymentID | Paid |  | Total |
| 1          | Smith    | 1             | 150   | 1         | 20   |  |       |
| 1          | Smith    | 1             | 150   | 3         | 40   |  |       |
| 1          | smith    | 3             | 30    | 1         | 20   |  |       |
| 1          | smith    | 3             | 30    | 3         | 40   |  |   240 |
+------------+----------+---------------+-------+-----------+------+--+-------+
```

Notice each transaction ID has to be paired with the payment ID thus the record and amounts are doubled, or tripped or quadrupled, depending on how many records are needed to resolve the M:M between transaction and payment.  in effect since no relationship has been defined, the table is cross joining all customer payment records to all customer transaction records.

Now if you had a way to tie payments to transactions such that they were a 1:1 relationship then we wouldn't need the subqueries.  However, since I doubt you could ever do that (customers could do partial payments; thus you need to support 1:M); I would recommend summing up in an inline view before the joins.

When you join these three tables you get 4 records not 2.  1 Customer Record * 2 payments records * 2 transactions = 4.  Now each payment is duplicated once for each record in transaction thus a payment of $10 occurs twice if 2 transactions exist.  To solve this problem you must total the records before the joins; thereby creating a 1:1:1 relationship and the artificial inflated count/totals go away.

As a note: you need to `nz` (take the first non null value) for the total price and total paid for situations which include no payments or transactions for a customer.  Say no payments had occurred for customer one  when you take 150+30 you would get 180 subtract null and you get null.  thus NZ is important to handle situations where payment or transaction have not occurred for a customer.

```
SELECT c.LastName
     , nz(T.[Total Price],0)
     , nz(P.[Total Paid],0)
     , nz(T.[Total Price],0)- nz(P.[Total Paid],0) AS Balance
FROM [Customers] c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(Payments.paid) as [Total Paid], customerID 
           FROM payments 
           GROUP BY customerID ) p
  ON P.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(Transactions.price) as [Total Price], customerID  
           FROM Transactions 
           GROUP BY customerID) t
  ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that absolutely meets your requirement

```
select a.lastname,a.tot_payment,b.tot_trans,(b.tot_trans-a.tot_payment) as balance 
from (select c.id,lastname,sum(p.price) tot_payment--,sum(t.price) 
from customers c
left join payments p on c.id = p.custid
group by lastname,c.id) a
join 
(select c.id,sum(t.price) tot_trans
from customers c
left join transactions t on t.custid = c.id
group by c.id)b
on a.id = b.id
```